# Getting Error on Fetching Data from two different DE into Email Template in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template

I am trying to get the data from two different Data extensions DE A  has columns fname, Lname, Contact ID, Email, Phone, Account ID and DE B which is Salesforce object DE has Account ID, Owner ID, Address, appointmentDate.
I want to show name, phone from DE A and Owner ID, Address, apptdate from DE B. Below is my AMPScript code for the same.

```
%%[
SET @Phone = [Phone]
SET @Name = [First Name]
SET @Email = [Email]
set @Contactid = attributevalue("Contact id")
set @orderrows = LookupRows("Testing_DE_Name","Contact id", @Contactid)
set @orderRowCount = rowcount(@orderrows)
if @orderRowCount > 0 then
for @i = 1 to @orderRowCount do
set @row = row(@orderRowCount, @i)
set @Contact_id = field(@row,"Contactid")
set @ServAddress = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Service_Custom_Address__c","Contactid",@Contact_id) 
set @Appt_Date = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Quote_Appointment_Date__c","Contactid",@Contact_id)
set @Advisorname = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Opportunity Owner ID field","Contactid",@Contact_id) 


%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%
No User Details were found
%%[ endif ]%%
IF NOT EMPTY (@Name) THEN
SET @Greeting = Propercase(@Name)
SET @Greeting = "Homeowner"
ENDIF
```

After adding above code to the email template,  I am getting Personalization errors as attached with this query.
[image]
Please help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AMPscript blocks must be surrounded with `%%[ ]%%` I don't see you complying with the syntax.

I have made some modifications, you can try something like this:

```
%%[
    set @Phone = [Phone]
    set @Name = [First Name]
    set @Email = [Email]
    set @Contactid = attributevalue("Contact id")
    set @orderrows = LookupRows("Testing_DE_Name","Contact id", @Contactid)
    set @orderRowCount = rowcount(@orderrows)
    if @orderRowCount > 0 then
    for @i = 1 to @orderRowCount do
        set @row = row(@orderRowCount, @i)
        set @Contact_id = field(@row,"Contactid")
        set @ServAddress = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Service_Custom_Address__c","Contactid",@Contact_id) 
        set @Appt_Date = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Quote_Appointment_Date__c","Contactid",@Contact_id)
        set @Advisorname = lookup("Oppotunity Salesforce DE","Opportunity Owner ID field","Contactid",@Contact_id) 
]%%
<!-- Display something here? -->
%%[next @i]%%

%%[ else ]%%
No User Details were found
%%[ endif ]%%

%%[
    if not empty(@Name) then
        set @Greeting = Propercase(@Name)
    else        
        set @Greeting = "Homeowner"
    endif
]%%
```

Comment: It has solve my issue but now I am getting another error on the preview @Duc Le Mu Error message is mentioned below: "" The Subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.  *Row function call was passed a rowset (parameter 1) of an unsupported type Function: row(@orderRowCount, @i) RowSet Type: Int32